# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am unable to login to MySQL under ubuntu 14.04 through putty.
I can however access it on PhpMyAdmin

```
whereis mysql
/usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz

ps -eaf | grep -in mysql
134:ubuntu   27235 17772  0 05:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -in mysql

sudo service mysql status
mysql: unrecognized service

sudo netstat -tlpn | grep mysql
[blank]
```

What might be the problem?

1. Has mysql been started as a service?
2. Since its a root user login, I think it's not a permissions issue

Any ideas?